# what is the formula for calculating the number of this?

Tags: list-manipulation

When I try the following codes

```
Sum[f[n, l, m], {n, 1, 10}, {l, 0, n - 1}, {m, 0, 9}] // Dimensions
```

or

```
Table[f[n, l, m], {n, 1, 10}, {l, 0, n - 1}, {m, 0, 9}] // 
  Flatten // Dimensions
```

Mathematica returns `550`. what is the general formula for calculating the number of members?

Comment: `Length` is for 1D-lists and `Dimensions` is for matrices. If you execute `Length` on a matrix, it will count its rows or the first dimension. Not sure what you mean by general formula.

Comment: @Syed I mean how can I calculate the total members of a table?

Comment: Please elaborate why you are not satisfied with the `Flatten` approach that gives you  `550`?

Comment: To count the members, you could do `Sum[1, {n, 1, 10}, {l, 0, n - 1}, {m, 0, 9}]` which returns 550 directly. This also works if you leave some bounds unspecified, for example `Sum[1, {n, 1, a}, {l, 0, n - 1}, {m, 0, b}]` returns $\frac12 a (a+1) (b+1)$.

Comment: To count the `f[...]` entries in your table: `Count[t, f[_, _, _], \[Infinity]]` that gives `550` and you can change the levelspec as required where `t` is your table.

Comment: Your formulas seem to work fine.  But to be sure they're giving what you want, you should instead try a test case that is small enough that you can easily check it manually.  Thus I'd recommend instead trying `Sum[f[n, l, m], {n, 1, 3}, {l, 0, n - 1}, {m, 0, 2}]` and `Table[f[n, l, m], {n, 1, 3}, {l, 0, n - 1}, {m, 0, 2}]`. You can readily count up the components and determine that, in both cases, it's 18, which is what you get with both `Sum[f[n, l, m], {n, 1, 3}, {l, 0, n - 1}, {m, 0, 2}]//Dimensions` and `Table[f[n, l, m], {n, 1, 3}, {l, 0, n - 1}, {m, 0, 2}]//Flatten//Dimensions`.

Comment: @Syed my mean was a general mathematical formula, not using Mathematica commands

Comment: @Roman Thanks a lot. you hit the spot. It was what I exactly meant: a general mathematical formula.

Comment: From left to right, the first two loops contribute a factor of `Binomial[10+1,2]` and the last contributes a factor of `(9+1)-0`. (I belabor the arithmetic to indicate how these are based on the loop bounds.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number is given by `Total[Range[a]]*(b + 1)` where `a` and `b` are in

```
Table[f[n, l, m], {n, 1, a}, {l, 0, n - 1}, {m, 0, b}
```

As a formula

[image]

Same as Roman's neat answer, but obtained by inspecting the tables.

For example

```
tab = Table[f[n, l, m], {n, 1, 3}, {l, 0, n - 1}, {m, 0, 1}];
Length[Flatten[tab]]
Column[tab]
```

> ```
> 12
>
> {{f[1,0,0],f[1,0,1]}}
> {{f[2,0,0],f[2,0,1]},{f[2,1,0],f[2,1,1]}}
> {{f[3,0,0],f[3,0,1]},{f[3,1,0],f[3,1,1]},{f[3,2,0],f[3,2,1]}}
> ```

The number of elements is

```
Total[Range[3]]*2
```

> 12